# Converting Crystal Report to SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, crystal-reports-2008, ssrs-2012, crystal-reports-8.5

Below expression is in crystal report

```
If {Databasetable.Column1} = "1" then 
stringVar x := "G" else     
If{Databasetable.Column1} = "2" then     
stringVar x := "IN " else        
If{Databasetable.Column1} = "3" then     
stringVar x := "SH ";    
X + {Databasetable.Column2}
```

I need to convert the above expression to SSRS Expression. Please, could anyone help on this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Switch(
Fields!DatabaseColumn1.Value = 1, "G",
Fields!DatabaseColumn1.Value = 2, "IN ",
Fields!DatabaseColumn1.Value = 3, "SH "
) & Fields!DatabaseColumn2.Value
```

Let me know if this can help you.